# ABAP JSON Writer using incorrect Date and Time Output?

Tags: json, transformation, abap

[Valid JSON data types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)    do not include dates. So why is SAP adding '-' ?

```
   data:
        lo_writer type ref to cl_sxml_string_writer,
        lo_xmldoc type ref to if_ixml_document,
        lv_xml type string,
        l_xstring type xstring,
        l_descr_ref type ref to cl_abap_typedescr.

   lo_writer = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json
                                             no_empty_elements  = '' ).

   call transformation id source JSON_ROOT_NODE = SY-DATUM
                         result xml lo_writer.

   l_xstring  = lo_writer->get_output( ).

   r_json = /AXO/MC_Tools=>xstring2string(  i_xstring     = l_xstring
                                           i_encoding    = 'UTF-8'   ).
```

**Result  "YYYY-MM-DD"  instead of "YYYYMMDD"**

Why ? 
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

You are right that JSON does not define a data type. SAP chose to represent a date as a string, which is a perfectly valid choice and conforms at least partially to the [ISO 8601 approach favored by other implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/218890). I do not believe there is anything to "fix" here other than perhaps the receiving application.

Comment: Given that Javascript does and that many use 8601 then you could argue SAP has  done it correctly. Unfornately I cant change the consumer expecting YYYYMMDD.   https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime